# SQL fill new column dependant on uniqueness of other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in the database that has among others 2 columns named item and slot. I want to create another column (call it cid) that is filled with numbers so that:

1. two rows that have the same item and same slot always have the same cid
2. rows with different item may have the same cid
3. the amount of distinct cid values is minimal
4. rows with the same item but different slot need to have different cid

If possible I'd like to just run an sql query that does that.

edit by request:

```
| item | slot | what cid should be
| a    | x    | 1
| a    | y    | 2
| a    | y    | 2
| a    | z    | 3
| b    | x    | 1
| b    | y    | 2
| b    | q    | 3
| c    | x    | 1
```

Comment: I think setting `cid` to a constant like `1` satisfies those conditions.

Comment: Sorry! been thinking about this so long I forgot to mention one condition. added it

Comment: You should add sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want just by enumerating the slots for each item:

```
   select t.*,
          (@cid := if(@i = item, if(@s = slot, @cid, if(@s := slot, @cid + 1, @cid + 1))
                      if(@i := item and @s := 0, 1, 1)
                     )
          ) as cid
   from t cross join
        (select @i := -1, @cid := 0, @s := 0) param
   order by item;
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy condition 1 but I may be able to work it out from there once I fully understand that query.